# Stack overflow exception on trying to assign a string to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, events, input, text

I have a simple textbox `TextChanged` event, that checks the string entered by the user in the field.

```
private void Phone_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     string phone = Phone.Text;
     if (phone.Length > 2 && phone.Length < 6)
     {
          string digit = Convert.ToString(phone[phone.Length - 1]);
          bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(digit, out int n);
          if (!isNumeric)
          {
               phone = phone.Substring(0, phone.Length - 1);
               Phone.Text = phone;
          }
      }
}
```

But when I try to compile it, I get `System.StackOverflowException` on line `Phone.Text = phone;`. I tried to change  `Substring()` to `Remove()`, but I still have this error. I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is there in your question itself. You are changing the text at the end of the method, which again triggers the text changed method and will keep doing that endlessly. So it results in a Stack overflow exception. This is what the compiler gets from your code ad hence raises a compile-time exception.

I suggest you handle the event before the text change and do not let the invalid text get in the textbox in the first place.

Comment: BTW, this could also be done by dettaching the event handler, changing the text, and then reattaching the event handler back.